# javascript automatic memoization of function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement memoization in javascript.
here's the code:

```
function memoize(func) {
    var history = {}

    var inner = function(n) {
        if (n in history) {
            return history[n];
        }
        let result = func(n)
        history[n] = result;
        return result;
    }
    return inner;
}

function fib(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
}
/*
fib = memoize(fib);
console.log(fib(20)) // O(n)
*/
/*
fib2 = memoize(fib);
console.log(fib2(20)) // O(2^n)
*/
```

it works.. I can calculated values in O(n) but I lost the original function. any way to still have the original fib function accessible?
thanks

Comment: Don't reassign `fib`? Instead, assign the returned function from `memoize()` to another variable name

Comment: @NickParsons doesn't work. it doesn't calculate in O(n)

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo, but in the `fib2` you would be passing the result of `memoize(fib)` and not the `fib` recursive function

Comment: @about14sheep no I tried to show 2 ways I tried to implement it, when I reassigned the fib name it returns results in O(n). the second example works in O(2^n) while I didn't ressign fib name. sorry about the confussion they are in different comments now

Comment: Looks like someone already did this... and they use the fibonacci function as an example: https://codeburst.io/understanding-memoization-in-3-minutes-2e58daf33a19

Comment: @J.Titus no good. I tried to change the initializtion of the fib variable in the last section of the article to receive the function from outside and it run O(2^n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain the original un-memoized version of `fib` you'll need to modify `fib` in some way, such as passing your recursive function as an argument. Otherwise, the recursive `fib` calls will remain as the un-memoized versions of your function.

eg:

```js
function memoize(func) { // potentially update this to accept as hash function to calculate the key for `history` to make this more generic
  var history = {}
  var inner = function(n, ...args) {
    if (n in history) {
      return history[n];
    }
    let result = func(n, ...args);
    history[n] = result;
    return result;
  }
  return inner;
}

function fib(n, recursiveFn = fib) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return n;
  }
  return recursiveFn(n - 1, recursiveFn) + recursiveFn(n - 2, recursiveFn)
}

const fastFib = memoize(fib);
console.log(fastFib(40, fastFib)); // O(n)
const slowFib = fib(40); // O(2^n)
console.log(slowFib);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, But is it possible to have fib accept a signle argument which is the num i want to compute?

Comment: @DarkLeader no, I don't think that is possible, because then you're expecting the same function to do two different things within the recursive calls. The function that is used to recurse can only be changed either by being overwritten (which you don't want to do as you want to keep the original), or by specifying the recursive function within the `fib` function. You could make a function such as `createFib(fn)` that uses `fn` to memorize your recursive calls eg: https://jsfiddle.net/mjL5ctn3/ this way, the function returned only expects 1 argument.

Comment: what do you mean by overwrite the original function? the reassignment of the variable fib I did in my code?

Comment: @DarkLeader yeah, the reassignment